# How can I Format the Date so that the fiscal week starts in December?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to format a date as follows: Y17W15, but there is no option to set the start of the year. However, there is no **consistent** way of calculating this. I cannot just subtract a month (other times I will need to show the month too), and I cannot just add 4 or 5 to the week field due to leap years, etc.

Our year starts on a Saturday that is closest to December 1. This means if November 30 is on a Saturday, the Fiscal Year will start on November 30.

Currently what I have is below, which works fine except it shows Y17W10. The easiest option in my head is to have a way to actually **set** the start of a fiscal year, but if I have to go through a bunch of if statements it's okay as long as it works.

```
MsgBox(Format(Now, """Y""yy""W""mm"""))
```

Thanks for your time!

I am aware that: [Given a 4-5-4 calendar and a date, how do I determine what fiscal week that date falls in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876667/given-a-4-5-4-calendar-and-a-date-how-do-i-determine-what-fiscal-week-that-date) exists but I am looking for an answer that isn't as hard-coded.

Michael

Comment: What do you consider to be "not as hard-coded"?

Comment: Essentially just looking for a shorter answer that people can easily manage once I leave (I'm just a 4 month co-op). If no other answers come up I will probably use that one :)

Comment: You could make an array of 7 items, with the middle item being December 1st, then calculate the weekdays for each of those 7 items. There should be only one saturday. Then calculate the weeknumber of that date and add/substract a value to go to 0 or 1

Comment: Yes I could, I'm curious if there is a way of setting a day as the start of the year systematically though.

Comment: Not fully tested, but a formula approach would be something along the lines of `="Y" & TEXT(A1,"yy") & "W" & INT((TODAY()-A1-WEEKDAY(A1,16)+1)/7)`  it would need some work to determine the closest of the Saturdays as this makes the proceeding Saturday, `-WEEKDAY`  I've got to go now, but will try to post more.

Comment: This should give you the nearest Saturday to December 1st `=DATE(2016,12,1)+IF((7-(WEEKDAY(DATE(2016,12,1))-1))<WEEKDAY(DATE(2016,12,1),16),(7-(WEEKDAY(DATE(2016,12,1))-1)),0-WEEKDAY(DATE(2016,12,1),16))`

Comment: In my above post A1 is the date 01/12/2016